# Given a distribution function, calculate $F(X \geq 7.3)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Say $X$ is a discrete random variable of the distribution function defined by the following:

$
F(a)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, a < 5\\
 0.17&\text{if}\, a < 6\\
 0.85&\text{if}\, a < 7\\
 0.93&\text{if}\, a < 8\\
 1&\text{if}\, a \geq 8\\
\end{cases}
$

Find $F(X \geq 7.3)$

For some reason, the answer is $1-0.93$ with the justification that it's supposed to be $1 - F(X < 7.3)$

But since discrete random variables are right continous, isn't $F(X < 7.3)$ going to be the sum of all inputs up to and including $a=7$? Why is it the sum of all inputs up to $a = 8$ here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ takes positive integer values, $X\lt 7.3$ really means $X=1,2,3\cdots,7$ which is equivalent to saying that $X\le 7$ or $X\lt 8$. Hence, you need $$1-0.93$$ “The sum of all inputs up to $a=8$” is *not* here, as $a\lt 8$ is a strict inequality.

Comment: Oh right, $a < 8$ does satisfy $x < 7.3$ my bad, thank you!